# how to make my own `PrimeQ` function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, homework, expression-test

How can I create my own function that verifies if the number is a `Prime` without using `PrimeQ`

```
ClearAll[primeQ2];

primeQ2[1] = False;

primeQ2[2] = True;

primeQ2[n_] := primeQ2[n] = Block[{p = 1, b = True},

While[b && p < Floor[Sqrt[N[n]]],
    p++;
    b = If[primeQ2[p], Not[Divisible[n, p]], True];
    ];
   b
];
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you asking if there is a more efficient implementation? Or something else?

Comment: Your implementation works as it is. As Rohit mentioned, it is unclear what you need, since you already avoid using `PrimeQ` in your code.

Comment: It uses https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14425 now, see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2898096

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

primeQ2[-1] = primeQ2[0] = primeQ2[1] = False;

primeQ2[n_Integer] := Module[
  {fi = FactorInteger[n]},
  fi == {{n, 1}} || fi == {{-1, 1}, {-n, 1}}]
```

Verifying by comparing with [`PrimeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeQ.html)

```
And @@ (PrimeQ[#] == primeQ2[#] & /@ Range[-10000, 10000])

(* True *)
```